# How do I setup an angularjs app on karma and nodejs

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

I would like to have a workflow for an angularjs app that uses mocha,chai instead of jasmine

I'm fine with setting up the bare project

```
npm init
npm install karma-mocha etc..
```

Is there a node way to install angularjs with a bare bones web project structure ? I'm not sold on yeoman yet...and looking for a leaner system

Thanks

Comment: Yeoman does exactly that.  What's not lean about it?

Comment: The angular generator for yeoman is really easy to run: `yo angular`

Comment: Running the commands manually I get a folder size of 40mb. Running yo angular I get a 190mb size folder - which is coming up to the limit for the cloud instances I use. That's my main concern.

Comment: A valid concern. It is true that the default generators install a lot of packages. Fortunately, you can create your own and there is a large number of community generators. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: I have to confess I am not exactly sure what you're looking for. If you're looking for some kind of template for an angular app you could maybe checkout the angular-seed? https://github.com/angular/angular-seed